# Defining my own proof environment?

Tags: environments, theorems

How would I define a `proof` environment that is basically used with

```
\begin{proof}
some proof here
\end{proof}
```

and it would be equivalent to:

```
\paragraph{Proof:} some proof here
\hfill \box
```

?

Comment: You probably want to add a “qed” box at the end of a proof. For this, it is enough to load a package such as `amsmath`.

Comment: Environments for proofs, theorems etc. are provided by either the `amsthm` or the `ntheorem` package.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With LaTeX syntax:

```
\newenvironment{proof}{\paragraph{Proof:}}{\hfill$\square$}
```

I assume here that you mean `\hbox{}` not `\box` in your code. 
The `\null` macro is short for `\hbox{}`. The `\box` is a TeX primitive and is more like `\usebox`.

Comment: this "box" at the end is quite invisible.  and if the proof ends with a display or a list, there's an extra blank line.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: It was not my original intension to *draw* a real box there because I took the `\box` macro of the OP with it's normal TeX meaning ;-) I modified the answer now to draw a real box. I don't have a quick fix for blank line issue. IMHO Someone should post an answer based on `amsthm` or a similar package.

Comment: This solution gave me an extra blank line at the *beginning*. Replacing `\paragraph{Proof:}}` with `\textbf{Proof:}` solved the problem.

Comment: @ntc2, I'm guessing that was an indent from \paragraph{} which can be suppressed with \noindent

Comment: @martin The square at the end is carried to the next line if in math display mode. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: @blackened: Maybe try a `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` before or after `\hfill`? (untested)

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that `\square` requires package `amssymb` to be included.

Comment: Beware! This fails to guarantee correct positioning of the QED symbol.

Answer (score 16):

You can also use the `amsthm` package which is a really nice and quick way of creating a proof.

**Implementation**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
    Your proof here.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

It will add `Proof` in italics at the beginning of the text given as argument and a white square (Q.E.D. symbol) at the end of it.

I found this easy solution at [1](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Theorems#Proofs). You can also look up there how you define your own environments using this package.

Comment: `amsthm`'s `proof` has the (known) flaw of introducing too much space when the proof directly starts with an enumerate or itemize environment.

Answer (score 3):

A small extension due to the case that the proofs are in the section "Proofs:"

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\newtheorem{pro}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{theo}[pro]{Theorem}

\newenvironment{myproof}[2] {\paragraph{Proof of {#1} {#2} :}}{\hfill$\square$}
\begin{document}
\begin{theo} \label{theo}
Hello
\end{theo}

\begin{myproof}{Theorem}{\ref{theo}}
This is the proof
\end{myproof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Beware! This fails to guarantee correct positioning of the QED symbol.

Answer (score 2):

```
\def\QEDmark{\ensuremath{\square}}
\def\proof{\paragraph{Proof:}}
\def\endproof{\hfill\QEDmark}
```

Comment: this one seems to be giving an error about \begin{document} missing whenever I try to use \begin{proof} \end{proof}

Comment: @kloop: I think it's the problem Martin pointed out - `\box` is a Tex primitive that looks ahead for the box number, and I guess then will eat the closing parenthesis.  I've changed the code.

Comment: Aaahhh, he meant to draw a box using `\box`, ok ... I sometimes I think to complicated.

Comment: The `\square` should be enclosed in `$` signs: `\def\QEDmark{$\square$}`.

Comment: @user31011: This is true if you use the environment (or \QEDmark) in running text.  If you use it in one of the AMS multiline math environments, putting in the '$' will cause an error.  If you might use it in either, try `\ensuremath`, but cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34830/when-not-to-use-ensuremath-for-math-macro

Comment: Beware! This fails to guarantee correct positioning of the QED symbol.

Answer (score 2):

I use ams package and changed a predefined "proof" environment in the following way and it works for me in LaTeX:

```
\renewenvironment{proof}{{\bf \emph{Proof.} }}{\hfill $\Box$ \\}
```

It changes the "proof" word to an italic bold "Proof.", adds a white QED. mark at the end of the last line of the proof, and creates a line space from whatever comes after the proof.

Comment: Please see [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://goo.gl/ECK5V) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/u98NT)

Comment: Beware! This fails to guarantee correct positioning of the QED symbol.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution using the `ntheorem` package. Here some explanations:

- `amssymb` is loaded to use `\blacksquare`
- The package `ntheorem` is loaded using the option `thmmarks` to support the placement of endmarks.
- `\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries}` sets the theorem title in bold.
- `\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}` preserves the normal text font for the theorem content.
- `\theoremseparator{:}` set `:` to be the separator between title and content.
- `\theoremsymbol{$\blacksquare$}` will place a solid black square at the end of every theorem environment.
- `\newtheorem*{proof}{Proof}` sets up a new unnumbered environment named `proof` with the default title "Proof".

Afterwards you can use `\begin{proof} ... \end{proof}` just like any other environment.

**Implementation**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremseparator{:}
\theoremsymbol{$\blacksquare$}
\newtheorem*{proof}{Proof}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
    We immediately see, that
    \[ 1 + 1 = 2. \]
    Thus the proof is done.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

> [image]

Comment: the box won't be there if the proof ends with a display or a list.  regarding ending with a display, that's not great style; better to finish off with text as in this example.  but a list might be harder to avoid.

Comment: Actually in some case the box will be there when ending with a dislay (although the order of appearance seems very random to me). Nevertheless I agree with you on the style issue.

Comment: The claimed output is not the one I get when i compile the given code.

Comment: OK I see: the figure is wrapped in a SE environment...