# Forcing qed symbol to stay on same page

Tags: symbols, environments

I've made this enviroment:

```
\newenvironment{rjesenje}{
\emph{\textbf{Rješenje:}}}{\vspace{0.1cm} 
\begin{flushright}
$\clubsuit $
\end{flushright}
}
```

And in my work I've got this output.
[image]

How do I force the symbol to stay on the same page?

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't appear to be showing "**Rješenje:**" at the bottom of the page. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Mico Is it OK now?

Comment: Thanks for this update. The only way to *guarantee* that the entire environment, including the ending `\clubsuit` symbol, will be placed on one page is to place it inside a `minipage` environment.

Comment: you've given this full encouragement to start a new page.  `flushright` begins with a `trivlist`, which in turn is always considered a good place for a page break.  what is needed is a mechanism similar to what is used for the `qed` symbol for the proof of a theorem.  there's discussion of that topic at [How to make all theorem-like environments have an ending symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201978)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ntheorem` and the `nonumberplain`theorem style. The placement of endmarks is automatic (even if the environment ends up in displayed equations). Here is a possible code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath, thref]{ntheorem}


\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\itshape\bfseries}
\theoremseparator{:}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\clubsuit}}
\newtheorem{rjesenje}{\hskip\parindent Rješenje}

\begin{document}

\begin{rjesenje}
  \lipsum[2-6] So
  \begin{equation*}
    \{x  ∈ E: x = 2\} = \{2\}\text{.}
  \end{equation*}
\end{rjesenje}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It says: ! Package ntheorem Error: Theorem style plain already defined.

Comment: Probably you're loading `amsthm`. You can't use  it with `ntheorem`. However you have a compatibility mode for `ntheorem`with the `amsthm` option.