# Square is not flushed-right at the end of newly defined \end environment

Tags: pdftex

I write the following code,

```
\documentclass[10pt, twocolumn, twoside, journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, color, enumerate, amsthm, graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz, subcaption, cite}
\usepackage{color, xcolor, soul, bm}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\usepackage{epsfig} 
\usepackage{psfrag}
\DeclareMathOperator{\diag}{diag}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newcommand{\JW}[1]{{\color{red}#1}}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\allowdisplaybreaks


\def\endtheorem{\hspace*{\fill}~\IEEEQEDopen\par\endtrivlist\unskip}
\def\endlemma{\hspace*{\fill}~\IEEEQEDopen\par\endtrivlist\unskip}
\def\endproposition{\hspace*{\fill}~\IEEEQEDopen\par\endtrivlist\unskip}
\def\endexample{\hspace*{\fill}~\IEEEQEDopen\par\endtrivlist\unskip}
\def\endremark{\hspace*{\fill}~\IEEEQEDopen\par\endtrivlist\unskip}
\def\enddefinition{\hspace*{\fill}~\IEEEQEDopen\par\endtrivlist\unskip}

\begin{document}
\title{My title}

\author{Mohammad}

\newcommand{\ty}{\color{yellow}}
\newcommand{\tb}{\color{blue}}
\newcommand{\tr}{\color{red}}
\newcommand{\tg}{\color{green}}


\maketitle

\thispagestyle{empty}
%\pagestyle{empty}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{abstract}
My abstract
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
    key words
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\begin{lemma}
This is my lemma and when the text happens to end near the right margin the symbol will be flushed left, not right.
\end{lemma}


\end{document}
```

I do see that a same question has been answered here: [How do I make all the theorem-alike environments have an ending symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201956/how-do-i-make-all-the-theorem-alike-environments-have-an-ending-symbol)

But I would like to know what the problem is with my \def commands and if I can fix them. If not please let me know an alternative.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Square is not flushed-right at the end of newly defined \end environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522139/square-is-not-flushed-right-at-the-end-of-newly-defined-end-environment)

Comment: do you really want end of proof markers at ends of lemmas and remarks? readers will find that confusing won't they?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I want the simple square (not the blacksquare) at the of lemmas and remarks.

Comment: can you make an example using a standard class ieeeaccess isn't in the standard distributions and it seems unreasonable to have to install it just to try your example

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Done.

Comment: I cant reproduce your problem. Square id always and the right border of lemma as expected. Of course, if for it is not space on the end of line, it appear in the next line. This also happen if int last line is displayed equation.

Comment: @Zarko The caution is reported here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201956/how-do-i-make-all-the-theorem-alike-environments-have-an-ending-symbol But there is no remedy found for it.