# Reproducing P. Aluffi's Definition/Theorem style

Tags: formatting, texworks, newtheorem

Currently reading [P. Aluffi's: *Algebra: Chapter 0*](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/algebra-chapter-0) and I really like the way theorems, definitions, etc. are emphasized by a lower right corner symbol ([`\rlcorner`](https://oeis.org/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_mathematical_symbols#Delimiters)). For reference

> [image]

I have tried recreating this formatting by manually inserting `\hfill$\rlcorner$` in the following way

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{exam}{Example}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{im}

\begin{document}

\begin{exam}
A complex
$$\cdots\longrightarrow M\overset\beta\longrightarrow N\longrightarrow0\longrightarrow\cdots$$
is exact at $N$ if and only if $\beta$ is an epimorphism.\par
Indeed, the complex is exact at $N$ if and only if $\im\beta=$ kernel of the trivial homomorphism $N\to0$, that is, $\im\beta=N$.\hfill$\lrcorner$
\end{exam}
\begin{definition} A {\it short exact sequence} is an exact complex of the form
$$0\longrightarrow M\overset\alpha\longrightarrow N\overset\beta\longrightarrow0.$$\hfill$\lrcorner$
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Anyway, I am not happy with this solution as, on the one hand, it does not seem efficient and, one the otehr hand, I am not able to adjust the height of the second `\rlcorner` to match the excerpt (writing `$$[Diagramm].\hfill\rlcorner$$` does not work).

> Could someone help me out? I would prefer to declare this style within the preamble for all kinds of theorem enviroments at once.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: But are your problem the tips of the arrows that must be curved and long?

Comment: @Sebastiano No?

Comment: First of never use `$$....$$` it is not LaTeX and it does not support LaTeX configuration. Her you can use `\tag*{$\lrcorner$}`, but guess what `$$...$$` is not supported by `\tag`. You can also use `ntheorem` (it cannot be used with `amsthm`), it supports adding endmarker to all theorem like envs (incl proof). It also have the feature to move the marker into math ending the theorem. Something `amsthm` does not support. Note that the endmarker in `ntheorem` is fragile in the sense that `\end{env}` should **never** have  blank line before it.

Comment: Is this helpful? [How to make all theorem-like environments have an ending symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201978)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes! Thank you kindly. I think you can even consider my post as a duplicate if the linked one.