# How can I insert the black little square at the end of each question in LaTeX like this picture?

Tags: overleaf, exam, latex3

[image: How can I insert the black little square at the end of each question in LaTeX like this picture?]

How can I insert the black little square at the end of each question in LaTeX like this picture?

Comment: If you're willing to use a theorem-like environment, and `amsthm`, this question provides a method: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/201956

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find your solution with AMS-theorem extension ([short](https://ctex.org/documents/packages/math/amsthdoc.pdf) and [long](https://www.ams.org/arc/tex/amscls/amsthdoc.pdf) docs)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
    \theoremstyle{definition} % default is plain
    \renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$} % standard is white
    \newtheorem{myquestion}{Question} % prefix numbering
    \section{Test}
    \begin{myquestion}
        Countries acros the world have been growing persistently since at least year 1200.
    \end{myquestion}
    \begin{myquestion}
        We use a logarithmic scale to plot the graph of a variable.
    \end{myquestion}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Denoting the end of example/remark](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16453/)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\providecommand*{\blacksquare}{\rule{1ex}{1ex}}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}[section]
\AtBeginEnvironment{question}{%
  \pushQED{\qed}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}%
}
\AtEndEnvironment{question}{\popQED\endquestion}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}

\begin{question}
  Countries across the world have been growing persistently since at
  least year 1200.
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  We use the logarithmic scale to plot the graph of a variable so that
  the same growth rates at different levels of that variable appear as
  the same slopes of the graph.
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

Remove `[section]` if you don't want the counter to be section-dependent.

[image]

Comment: This really makes the question a duplicate.