# Too much space between the math expression and the symbol at the end of a statment of theorem, remark etc

Tags: spacing, theorems

I've added a diamond symbol to the end of my theorem (and other) environments:

[image]

However, when I use any display math at the end of the theorem, the diamond gets set too low:

[image]

Is there some way to get the diamond up, **automatically** so it is aligned (or almost aligned) with the end of the math expression? Something like this (I used `\tag*{\diamond}`):

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dsfont}

%im using this font (in case it is important)
\usepackage{tgbonum}
\newcommand\hmmax{0}
\newcommand\bmmax{0}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

%using the package amsthm to define theorems lemmas, corolaries etc.
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thrm1}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{remark1}[thrm1]{Remark}
\newtheorem{prop1}[thrm1]{Proposition}

%this new commands let me end every statment of a theorem, remark or proposition with any symbol, in this case i'm using "$\diamond$"

\newcommand{\thmsymbol}{$\diamond$}

\newenvironment{thrm}{\begin{thrm1}%
  \renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\thmsymbol}\pushQED{\qed}}%
  {\popQED\end{thrm1}}
  
\newenvironment{remark}{\begin{remark1}%
  \renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\thmsymbol}\pushQED{\qed}}%
  {\popQED\end{remark1}}

\newenvironment{prop}{\begin{prop1}%
  \renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\thmsymbol}\pushQED{\qed}}%
  {\popQED\end{prop1}}
\begin{document}



\section*{So, my problem is the following.}

\begin{thrm} Every end of a theorem, proposition, remark etc, is marked with the symbol ``$\diamond$''.
\end{thrm}
\begin{remark}
As you can see, the diamond symbol is positioned immediately at the end of the sentence. I mean, it is just right here $\rightarrow\rightarrow\rightarrow\rightarrow\rightarrow$
\end{remark}

\section*{My problem is when I use math mode}

\begin{prop} When I use math mode, the position of the $\diamond$ is too low
    $$\int_0^1 x \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \quad \text{i mean, it goes waaaay down: } \rightarrow\rightarrow\rightarrow\rightarrow\rightarrow\rightarrow\rightarrow \searrow $$
\end{prop}

My question is: \textbf{is there some way to get the diamond up, automatically?} aligned (or almost aligned) with the end of the math expression, something like this:

\begin{prop1} Here is Euler's formula 
\begin{align*}
e^{ix} = \cos (x) + i \sin (x) \quad\quad \forall x \in \mathds{R} \tag*{$\diamond$}
\end{align*}
\end{prop1}
And I can continue without any problem, instead of dealing with: 
\begin{prop} Here is Euler's formula 
\begin{align*}
e^{ix} = \cos (x) + i \sin (x) \quad\quad \forall x \in \mathds{R} 
\end{align*}
\end{prop}
\noindent Too much space between the math expression and the diamond symbol!

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you read the `amsthm` user guide?  It explains the use of `\qedhere` to avoid the kind of spacing you're encountering when a proof ends with display math.  You might try that.  (I haven't vetted the code changes to see if they do the same thing.)  But `\qedhere` doesn't work with `$$`, so you should change that to `\[...\]` or `equation*.

Comment: This question may be helpful: [How to make all theorem-like environments have an ending symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201978)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `\qedhere` for the cases when the QED symbol has to appear in a math display or at the end of a list (`enumerate` or `itemize`).

However, you ***mustn't*** use `$$`: see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503). Here it's not just “preferable”, it is ***crucial***. Any standard `amsmath` display environment accepts `\qedhere`.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{thrm1}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{remark1}[thrm1]{Remark}
\newtheorem{prop1}[thrm1]{Proposition}

\newcommand{\thmsymbol}{$\diamond$}

\newenvironment{thrm}{\begin{thrm1}%
  \renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\thmsymbol}\pushQED{\qed}}%
  {\popQED\end{thrm1}}
  
\newenvironment{remark}{\begin{remark1}%
  \renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\thmsymbol}\pushQED{\qed}}%
  {\popQED\end{remark1}}

\newenvironment{prop}{\begin{prop1}%
  \renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\thmsymbol}\pushQED{\qed}}%
  {\popQED\end{prop1}}


\begin{document}

\section*{So, my problem is the following.}

\begin{thrm}
Every end of a theorem, proposition, remark etc, is marked with the symbol ``$\diamond$''.
\end{thrm}

\begin{remark}
As you can see, the diamond symbol is positioned immediately at the end of the sentence. 
I mean, it is just right here $\rightarrow\rightarrow\rightarrow\rightarrow\rightarrow$
\end{remark}

\section*{My problem is when I use math mode}

\begin{prop}
When I use math mode correctly, the position of the $\diamond$ is perfect
\[
\int_0^1 x \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \qedhere
\]
\end{prop}

\end{document}
```

I only left the relevant parts of the document.

[image]