# Is there a better way to define a second proof environment?

Tags: environments, theorems, proof-package

I've seen this post [Defining my own proof environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10123/defining-my-own-proof-environment) and I have a follow-up question, because the answers there are unsatisfying.

I would like to define *two* proof environments—one with a black qed square and one with a white qed square. I made the default proof environment to have a black qed symbol by the following code snippet:

```
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
```

I defined another proof environment by a modification of the [advice given in the page I mentioned above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10123/defining-my-own-proof-environment) and wrote the following:

```
\newenvironment{claimproof}[1]{\par\noindent\textit{Proof.}\space#1}{\hfill$\square$}
```

This seems like it works, but I ran into some edge cases where there are discrepancies between the two. The latter claimproof environment does not guarantee that the qed-box is placed at the same place where the default proof environment would place it. Here is an example where I found an actual difference.

**Picture 1** (uses custom `claimproof` environment with white qed-box).

[image]

**Picture 2** (uses default `proof` environment with black qed-box).

[image]

The `claimproof` environment fails to place the white box to the right (I could fix that by adding `\newline` but that would make unnecessary new lines that the default `proof` environment doesn't do). I want `claimproof` to act exactly the same way as the default `proof` environment works. Is there a less ad-hoc way to do this that actually replicates the true `proof` environment?

Comment: Well, most of those answers are unfortunately very disputable. None, except the ones based on `amsthm` or `ntheorem` fail to guarantee correct positioning of the tombstone (aka QED symbol).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code defines the environment `claimproof` as the `proof` environment from the `amsthm` package, but also redefines `\qedsymbol` at the beginning of the environment. Since the redefinition of `\qedsymbol` is done inside a group, it is only applied locally (inside the `claimproof` environment).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}

\newenvironment{claimproof}[1][\proofname]
{\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}\proof[#1]}
{\endproof}

\begin{document}
    \begin{proof}
        a proof with a hollow square as a Q.E.D
    \end{proof}

    \begin{claimproof}
        a proof with a solid square as a Q.E.D
    \end{claimproof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I thought it might be better to not modify the proof environment, and made `claimproof` to have a solid qed symbol. If you wish for the proof environment to have a solid square, you could save the original `\qedsymbol` and do the redefinition inside `claimproof` to the original symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}

\let\origqedsymbol\qedsymbol
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}

\newenvironment{claimproof}[1][\proofname]
{\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\origqedsymbol}\proof[#1]}
{\endproof}

\begin{document}
    \begin{proof}
        a proof with a solid square as a Q.E.D
    \end{proof}

    \begin{claimproof}
        a proof with a hollow square as a Q.E.D
    \end{claimproof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd use `\proofname` as the default value of the optional argumen. Otherwise this *is* the answer.

Comment: @egreg, thank you for the remark, you are right... I will edit.

Comment: This is perfect. Simple and avoids ad-hoc hacks. Thank you!

Comment: @MaximalIdeal you are welcome :)